# XSLT 1.0 check if duplicate, sum and remove

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to do a check:
If "ITEM.ITEM_NUMBER_IN" is more than one time with the same value.
-> Like here: 315024 is twice

We have to sum "ITEM.QUANTITY_12" and create one line instead of two.
-> But note, it could be, that the same "ITEM.ITEM_NUMBER_IN" is more than two times available.

XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SEEDESADV>
    <SEE_AG COPYRIGHT="SEEBURGER AG" CREATION_DATE="2007-05-09" MESSAGE="SEEDESADV_V3_0" MAPPING="RECA_AT_DESADV_D96A_IN" VERSION="1.0.74"/>
    <CNT>
        <IC>
            <REF_ON>00120925</REF_ON>
        </IC>
        <GRP>
            <MSG>
                <ME>
                    <MESSAGE_NUMBER>274103076</MESSAGE_NUMBER>
                </ME>
                <ASN>
                    <DATE>
                        <QUALIFIER>17</QUALIFIER>
                        <DATE>20220124</DATE>
                    </DATE>
                    <TXT>
                        <QUALIFIER>QUC</QUALIFIER>
                        <TEXT_LINE>ADD:BY#BY</TEXT_LINE>
                    </TXT>
                    <ITEM>
                        <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>10</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>                     
                        <ITEM_NUMBER_IN>323656</ITEM_NUMBER_IN>
                        <QUANTITY_12>1000</QUANTITY_12>
                        <QUANTITY_UNIT>PCE</QUANTITY_UNIT>
                    </ITEM>
                    <ITEM>
                        <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>20</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>                     
                        <ITEM_NUMBER_IN>315024</ITEM_NUMBER_IN>                     
                        <QUANTITY_12>6000</QUANTITY_12>
                        <QUANTITY_UNIT>PCE</QUANTITY_UNIT>                      
                    </ITEM>
                    <ITEM>
                        <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>30</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>                     
                        <ITEM_NUMBER_IN>315024</ITEM_NUMBER_IN>                     
                        <QUANTITY_12>5000</QUANTITY_12>
                        <QUANTITY_UNIT>PCE</QUANTITY_UNIT>
                    </ITEM>
                </ASN>
            </MSG>
        </GRP>
    </CNT>
</SEEDESADV>
```

XSLT:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
  <xsl:key name="group" match="ITEM" use="concat(ITEM_NUMBER_IN, QUANTITY_UNIT)"/> 
  
  
      <xsl:template match="ITEM">   
        <xsl:for-each select=".[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(ITEM_NUMBER_IN, QUANTITY_UNIT))[1])]">
            <xsl:choose>        
                <xsl:when test="not.[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(ITEM_NUMBER_IN, QUANTITY_UNIT))[1])]">                                    
                    <ITEM>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="LINE_ITEM_NUMBER"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="ITEM_NUMBER_IN"/>
                        <QUANTITY_12>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('group', concat(ITEM_NUMBER_IN, QUANTITY_UNIT))/QUANTITY_12), '#')"/>
                        </QUANTITY_12>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="QUANTITY_UNIT"/>
                    </ITEM>
                </xsl:when>            
                    <xsl:otherwise>                 
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>                    
                    </xsl:otherwise>                
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- delete empty nodes -->
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
<!-- delete empty nodes -->  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Correct:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SEEDESADV>
    <SEE_AG COPYRIGHT="SEEBURGER AG" CREATION_DATE="2007-05-09" MESSAGE="SEEDESADV_V3_0" MAPPING="RECA_AT_DESADV_D96A_IN" VERSION="1.0.74"/>
    <CNT>
        <IC>
            <REF_ON>00120925</REF_ON>
        </IC>
        <GRP>
            <MSG>
                <ME>
                    <MESSAGE_NUMBER>274103076</MESSAGE_NUMBER>
                </ME>
                <ASN>
                    <DATE>
                        <QUALIFIER>17</QUALIFIER>
                        <DATE>20220124</DATE>
                    </DATE>
                    <TXT>
                        <QUALIFIER>QUC</QUALIFIER>
                        <TEXT_LINE>ADD:BY#BY</TEXT_LINE>
                    </TXT>
                    <ITEM>
                        <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>10</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>                     
                        <ITEM_NUMBER_IN>323656</ITEM_NUMBER_IN>
                        <QUANTITY_12>1000</QUANTITY_12>
                        <QUANTITY_UNIT>PCE</QUANTITY_UNIT>
                    </ITEM>
                    <ITEM>
                        <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>20</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>                     
                        <ITEM_NUMBER_IN>315024</ITEM_NUMBER_IN>                     
                        <QUANTITY_12>11000</QUANTITY_12>
                        <QUANTITY_UNIT>PCE</QUANTITY_UNIT>                      
                    </ITEM>
                </ASN>
            </MSG>
        </GRP>
    </CNT>
</SEEDESADV>
```

Please let me know, if everything is clear.

Thanks for you help.

Best regards
Julian

Comment: Duplicates can be identified and summed through grouping, look into http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html for how to approach that with XSLT 1, then give it a try, if you get stuck show us what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: I tried and added it in my xslt-code

Comment: @juls_pro_37 It looks like you have copy/pasted some random code into your stylesheet. XSLT does not work that way.

Comment: yes, sometimes I had some case like that and wanted to try this way, but i don´t get it.

Comment: Read the article referenced above.

Comment: today i´ve changed the xslt - it seems more bether, but there is no calculation at "<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('group', concat(ITEM_NUMBER_IN, QUANTITY_UNIT))/QUANTITY_12), '#')"/>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve done it this way:

```html
<xsl:key name="item" match="ITEM" use="ITEM_NUMBER_IN"/>
  
  
      <xsl:template match="ASN">      
    <xsl:for-each select="//ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item', ITEM_NUMBER_IN)[1])]">
        <xsl:choose>        
            <xsl:when test="//ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item', ITEM_NUMBER_IN)[1])]">                                  
                <ITEM>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="LINE_ITEM_NUMBER"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ITEM_DESCRIPTION"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ITEM_NUMBER_IN"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ITEM_NUMBER_SA"/>
                    <QUANTITY_12>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('item', ITEM_NUMBER_IN)/QUANTITY_12)"/>
                    </QUANTITY_12>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="QUANTITY_UNIT"/>
                </ITEM>
            </xsl:when>            
                <xsl:otherwise>                 
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>                    
                </xsl:otherwise>                
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the grouping from the context of the parent (or ancestor) of the nodes being grouped.

Try it along these lines:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="ITEM" use="ITEM_NUMBER_IN"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ASN">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DATE | TXT"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item', ITEM_NUMBER_IN)[1])]">
        <ITEM>
            <xsl:copy-of select="LINE_ITEM_NUMBER | ITEM_NUMBER_IN"/>
            <QUANTITY_12>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('item', ITEM_NUMBER_IN)/QUANTITY_12)"/>
            </QUANTITY_12>
            <xsl:copy-of select="QUANTITY_UNIT"/>
        </ITEM>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```